# How to create Object for inner Class properly?

Tags: java

I'm practising dynamic programming and I do that by creating a bank project.
Here I want to have many customers and each of these customers can have many gift cards of different capacity.Hence I created a class giftcard1 within class customer.But how to instantiate it and add it. Such that I can get the giftcard details when I iterate over that customer.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Customer
{
    int id;
    String pwd;
    int gift;
    int pin;
    int bal=0;
    //int giftcard balance
    class giftcard1
    {
        int gift_bal;
        List<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner((System.in));
       List<Customer> l1=new ArrayList<Customer>();

       int choice=1;

       while(choice==1||choice==2)
       {
           System.out.println("1.Account Creation 2.Purchase");
           choice=sc.nextInt();
           cancel:
           for(int j=0;j<1;j++) {
               if (choice == 1) {
                   System.out.println("Please enter id and pwd");
                   int id1 = sc.nextInt();
                   String s = sc.next();
                   char c[] = s.toCharArray();
                   int i;
                   for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                       c[i] = (char) (c[i] + 1);
                       //System.out.print(c[i]);
                   }
                   String s1 = new String(c);
                   System.out.println(s1);
                   Customer cu = new Customer();
                   Customer.giftcard1 g=new cu.giftcard1();
//need help above
                   cu.id = id1;
                   cu.pwd = s1;
                   l1.add(cu);

                   System.out.println("1.GiftCCard 2.TopUP 3. Transaction History 4.Block 5.Logout");
                   int ch1 = sc.nextInt();
                   while ((ch1!=0)) {
                       if (ch1 == 1) {
                           int giftcard = (int) (Math.random() * 100000);
                           int pin = (int) (Math.random() * 10000);
                           cu.gift = giftcard;
                           cu.pin = pin;
                           System.out.println("Giftcard No " + giftcard + " " + "Pin " + pin);
                       }
                       if (ch1 == 2) {
                           System.out.println("Enter the amount needed to Recharge");
                           int amt = sc.nextInt();
                           if(amt>cu.bal)
                           {
                               System.out.println("Not enough Money");
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               g.gift_bal=amt;
                               g.l2.add(amt+" is added");
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I want to create an object g of class giftcard for  Customer object cu.

Comment: Try to make `giftcard1` as `static` class

Answer (score 3):

First I would recommend to learn the [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Second I would also recommend to move the `GiftCard`-class out of the `Customer`-class.

To store `n` `GiftCard`s you should add a `List<GiftCard>` to your `Customer`-class as a class member.

```java
class Customer {
    int id;
    String pwd;
    int gift;
    int pin;
    int bal=0;
    List<GiftCard> giftCards;
}

class GiftCard {
    int balance;
}
```

*Note* you should check out how to work with constructors.

So you create and store it:

```java
Customer customer = ...;
....

customer.giftCards = new ArrayList<>();

GiftCard card1 = new GiftCard();
card1.balance = 100;
customer.giftCards.add(card1);
```

Now the customer has 1 `GiftCard` with the `balance` `100`

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
Customer c = ...
Customer.giftcard1 g = c.new giftcard1();
```

You have to make both class visible by adding `public` modifier.